# Absolute GMT date on iPhone

Tags: iphone, date, notifications, local, gmt

I'm trying to get a date that represents noon GMT for a recurring local notification.

I need this local notification to fire at the exact moment to anyone using the app.

So far, I'm trying this:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setHour:12];
[dateComps setMinute:0];
[dateComps setMonth:1];
[dateComps setDay:1];
[dateComps setYear:2010];

NSDate *localDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneOffset;
NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];

localNotification.fireDate = gmtDate;
```

This isn't working, however.  Any suggestions?

Edit::
Will this work if I don't specify a time zone on the notfication:

```
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1284483600];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does setting the calendar's timezone to GMT work?

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setHour:12];
[dateComps setMinute:0];
[dateComps setMonth:1];
[dateComps setDay:1];
[dateComps setYear:2010]; 

[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSDate *gmtDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
```

Comment: Is this similar to my edit above, wherein you just create a date with the seconds from epoch that represent this time?  Damn, who would have thought this date stuff could be so tricky?

Comment: Yes, I think your edit will work too. Everyone will get the same offset from 1970 in GMT, so everyone will fire at the same time. Either should work (I would think...!)